# php-How to know if a character belongs to whitespace

Tags: php

I've tried this code but not working:

```
if($teststring == '/\s\s+/'){
    echo "character is whitespace:" . $numchar;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** `if($teststring == '/\s\s+/'){` Here you are comparing this `$teststring` with string literal `/\s\s+/`;

Instead use it like this.

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/\s\s+/',$teststring))
{
    echo "character is whitespace:" . $numchar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $string = "character is whitespace:" . $numchar;
$explode = explode(' ',$string);
if($explode[1] != ''){
  //there is a white space
}
```

explode string with space if array second is not blank than its have a white space.